# Send channel request from SSH server making `ssh_channel_accept_forward()` return on SSH client?

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming, libssh

I use the client code for direct and reverse port forwarding from the official tutorials: http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_forwarding.html

This code works perfectly when connecting the client to an OpenSSH server on Ubuntu 16.10, i.e., direct and reverse port forwarding is achieved.

However, consider the client code for reverse port forwarding (`web_server()`), which makes use of the following calls:

```
ssh_channel_listen_forward()

ssh_channel_accept_forward()
```

Using my own libssh server, the problem is that the client times out in the call to `ssh_channel_accept_forward()` with the following error message:

```
"No channel request of this type from server"
```

That is, the error message is printed by the following client code after waiting 1 minute:

```
  channel = ssh_channel_accept_forward(session, 60000, &port);
  if (channel == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error waiting for incoming connection: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(session));
    return SSH_ERROR;
  }
```

How do I construct a channel request on the server side, such that the client doesn't time out in `ssh_channel_forward_accept()` and a new forward channel is created? I've tried most of the API functions without luck...

Is there a specific API function for sending such channel request? If not, how do I accomplish the task of requesting the channel?

My code on the server side goes along the following lines, where the `ssh_channel_listen_forward()` request is captured by the following callback function:

```
void global_request(ssh_session session, ssh_message message, void *userdata) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("[Debug] global_request()\n");
    #endif
    struct session_data_struct *session_data = (struct session_data_struct*) userdata;
    ssh_message_global_request_reply_success(message, 8080);
    const char *addr = ssh_message_global_request_address(message);
    int port = ssh_message_global_request_port(message);
    printf("Received global request: %s:%d\n", addr, port);
    session_data->channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
    ssh_channel ch = ssh_message_channel_request_channel(message);
    if (ssh_channel_is_open(session_data->channel)) {
        printf("Channel is open!\n");
    }
}
```

However, as stated, the server is not making the client accept a new forward channel in the call to `ssh_channel_accept_forward()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: ***＋ 1*** for asking a SSH question that's actually about programming or development

Answer (score 1):

Your server code don't send request to open reverse tunnel to client side.
This channel: `session_data->channel` created not bound at server side. You can try to connect it, but in this case you should set subtype `"forwarded-tcpip"` manually.

This request: `ssh_message_channel_request_channel(message);`
returns NULL because port forwarding request has no channel field.

For initiation of reverse tunnel, that you can accept with `ssh_channel_accept_forward()` - you should connect to the bound listening port at the server side. (port number from `ssh_channel_listen_forward()` you know).

P.S. And don't use server callbacks to accept this request. Libssh still filter this message subtype from callback processing.

P.P.S. Read RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#page-7) and library source. It's completely readable and not that big

Comment: I'm still a little unsure about what to do.  Could you give an example of initiating a reverse tunnel?

Comment: For test you can simply connect to forwarded port with telnet.
Or create a socket at server side and connect it to forwarded port at localhost.

Comment: Could you describe more simply what the server side should do after receiving the forward-listen message?  I'm new, so I need small steps. Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: For setting a subtype manually you have to use internal library functions like
`rc = channel_open(channel,
                    "direct-tcpip",
                    CHANNEL_INITIAL_WINDOW,
                    CHANNEL_MAX_PACKET,
                    payload);`
but it's not recommended without complete understanding what are you doing.

Comment: After receiving forward listen message server should reply with

`byte     SSH_MSG_REQUEST_SUCCESS
 uint32   port that was bound on the server`

And wait for incoming connections on bound port. When connection occurs it should request new channel with type:
`byte      SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN
      string    "forwarded-tcpip"`
And pipe data from bound port to this channel and back.

Comment: I will try that! This comment makes much more sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that the server callback mechanism is buggy?

Comment: How would I use the internal open_channel function? If it is internal it is not included as part of the API? Shouldn't the API allow for forward connections? Otherwise the API is incomplete/insufficient?

Comment: _Are you saying that the server callback mechanism is buggy?_

It's not buggy it's just not supposed to process tunnels

` case SSH_REQUEST_CHANNEL_OPEN:
            if (msg->channel_request_open.type == SSH_CHANNEL_SESSION &&
                ssh_callbacks_exists(session->server_callbacks, channel_open_request_session_function))`

This if in messages.c - filter types of channel open requests

Comment: _How would I use the internal open_channel function?_
Just for clear understanding - what do you suppose to do via tunnel? Probably you need simple direct forward tunnel, but try to use reverse one.

Comment: I've recently started to read about the features of SSH and one of them is reverse port forwarding. Actually, I don't need it for much right now. I just want to learn how to do it. Having looked through the source code of libssh once again, how do I use the `open_channel` function when it is internal? I don't understand why there are no functions in libssh.h or server.h that I can use for requesting the channel? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Could you add some code to you answer for completeness :-)?

Comment: In the plain C we can't make private declarations. So formally you can use any function in library, but maintainers also feel free to change non-documented in API code without any notifications.
Code for reverse tunnel in library tutorial works well, you just need standalone application to make http GET-request on tunneled port

Comment: But, the internal functions are not exposed from the libssh.so library? Only library functions are declared with LIBSSH_API?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I miss static in definition. You could not use this func without lib edit.

Comment: so what you are saying is that I need to modify the source and recompile/install? I think it is weird that libssh provide no support for reverse forwarding by default.

Comment: It supports. You have to use it correctly. Reverse forward tunnel will create channel automatically after you make connection to forwarded port. You shouldn't do it manually

Comment: It isn't working for me :-( - Have you tried it? If so, would you add snippets of your code to your answer?

Comment: Kind of a metacode
    - session initialization (set options, connect, authorization)
    - set remote forward (ssh_channel_listen_forward)
    while(!channel = ssh_channel_accept_forward(session, 0, 
    &tunneledPort)) {
      sleep(SLEEPTIME);
    }
    while(true)
      ssh_select(socket, channel)
      data piping between socket and channel
      if (eof from either side) {
        flush remaining data
        break;
      }
    }
    clearing (disconnect channel, session, socket)
Like this

Comment: This I do. What I need is a way for the client to open the channel. The server waits in ssh_channel_accept_forward(), since the client never sends the channel request.

Comment: Lets define what is cllient and what is server in your app.
You have client  it initialize session to server, right?
Than client set remote forward in session, so it opens forwarded port on server side
Than client should wait to accept forward.
When connection to forwarded port on server side occurs - server initiate an channel request back to client, who accept_forward it and communicate.

It's reverse forwarding.

Comment: I guess this is what I do. Would you look at my code to see where things go wrong? If so, how can I share it with you?